# Google Maps v3 - Replacing marker as infoWindow display

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've found alot out there on customizing a marker/infoWindow separately but is it possible to make the infoWindow be used as the marker instead? (Only displaying the infoWindow). I've tried toying the marker css as `display: hidden;` and few other things but no luck.

```
var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7831,-122.4039),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var acOptions = {
      types: ['establishment']
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'),acOptions);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds',map);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      infoWindow.close();
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>');
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(e){

        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

      });
    });
```

Comment: I've changed the `setPosition` to `marker.hide.setPosition` however I still have to click on the location to show the infoWindow.

Comment: If you don't want the marker. Don't add it to the map.  You don't _need_ a marker to display an infowindow.

Comment: How could i go about that in my code? `infoWindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);` doesn't quite work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  infoWindow.close();
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);
  }
  infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>');
  infoWindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
  infoWindow.open(map);
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_onlyInfoWindow.html)